# What is the difference between following two sentences

Tags: pronouns

John has three jars.

> He decided to sell **them**.

Or

> He decided to sell **that**.

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 2):

> He decided to sell **[them](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/them)**.
>
> PRONOUN
>
> 1 *[third person plural]* Used as the object of a verb or preposition to refer to two or more people or things previously mentioned or easily identified.
>   ‘I bathed the kids and read them stories’

You would use **it** for a singular item in the same structure.